# How to extract all the instruments played in a midi file format?

Tags: c++, midi

I am working on "de-multiplexing a midi file", which means extracting all the the instruments played on channel at any moment in the song. I thought that the solution could be extracting the instrument played on one note at the time and store it in a data structure. I am supposed to use C++.

Does anyone know a good reference to start with? I have no idea about how to manipulate midi files using C++; I just read some good references about midi structure but no more.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php). It has a lot of MIDI functions that may help you figure out what you need to know. You can also look [here](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) for a description of the MIDI file format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I tried to work with Juce but it doesn't really help, with Ju7ce I needed to use the "Introducer" which is Juce interface, but what I need to do is extracting those features using my own program on emacs because I have other data structure to manipulate also.
Thanks,

Comment: I recommended JUCE so that you could look at the source code to see how it works with MIDI files. Between that and the MIDI file format, that's all the information you need. If you get stuck on a specific problem, post some code with a question. That's how to get the most out of Stack Overflow. General questions like this one won't get you much help.